# How to implement asynchronous code that looks synchronous mimicking async / await?

Tags: asynchronous, networking, scheme, chez-scheme

Otherwise said, I want to rely on `epoll` (or similar) to write asynchronous network code that looks like regular code that is without relying on callbacks.

The code must look like synchronous code but unlike synchronous code instead of blocking to wait for network io, it must suspend the current *coroutine* and restart it when the file descriptor is ready.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought to achieve that was relying on generators and `yield`. But [this was a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614788/implement-yield-and-send-in-scheme) that was partly mis-guided by the fact that python used to abuse `yield from`.

Anyway, guile fibers was a great insipiration and [I adapted it to chez scheme](https://git.sr.ht/~amz3/chez-scheme-arew/tree/1656b24f3044f64a690fc07d44138e9071ff3d01/src/arew/untangle.scm#L16).

Here is an example server code:

```
(define (handler request port)
  (values 200 #f (http-get "https://httpbin.davecheney.com/ip")))

(untangle (lambda ()
            (run-server "127.0.0.1" 8888)))
```

The `handler` returns its IP according the httpbin service. The code look synchronous with the help of call/cc actually call/1cc.

`untangle` will initiate the event loop with a lambda passed as argument!

Here is the definition of `run-server`:

```
(define (run-server ip port handler)
  (log 'info "HTTP server running at ~a:~a" ip port)
  (let* ((sock (socket 'inet 'stream 'ipv4)))
    (socket:setsockopt sock 1 2 1) ;; re-use address
    (socket:bind sock (make-address ip port))
    (socket:listen sock 1024)
    (let loop ()
      (let ((client (accept sock)))
        (let ((port (fd->port client)))
          (spawn (lambda () (run-once handler port)))
          (loop))))))
```

As you can see there is no callback. The only thing that is somewhat different from simple synchronous webserver is the `spawn` procedure that will handle the request in its own coroutine. In particular `accept` is asynchronous.

`run-once` will just pass the scheme request to `handler` and take its 3 values to build the response. Not very interesting. The part that looks synchronous, but is actually asynchronous is `http-get` above.

I will only explain, how accept works, given http-get requires to introduce custom binary ports, but suffice to say it is the same behavior...

```
(define (accept fd)
  (let ((out (socket:%accept fd 0 0)))
    (if (= out -1)
        (let ((code (socket:errno)))
          (if (= code EWOULDBLOCK)
              (begin
                (abort-to-prompt fd 'read)
                (accept fd))
              (error 'accept (socket:strerror code))))
        out)))
```

As you can see it calls a procedure `abort-to-prompt` that we could call simply `pause` that will "stop" the coroutine and call the prompt handler.

`abort-to-prompt` works in cooperation with `call-with-prompt`.

Since chez scheme doesn't have prompts I emulate it using two one shot continuations [`call/1cc`](https://www.scheme.com/csug7/control.html#./control:s21)

```
(define %prompt #f)
(define %abort (list 'abort))

(define (call-with-prompt thunk handler)
  (call-with-values (lambda ()
                      (call/1cc
                       (lambda (k)
                         (set! %prompt k)
                         (thunk))))
    (lambda out
      (cond
       ((and (pair? out) (eq? (car out) %abort))
        (apply handler (cdr out)))
       (else (apply values out))))))

(define (abort-to-prompt . args)
  (call/1cc
   (lambda (k)
     (let ((prompt %prompt))
       (set! %prompt #f)
       (apply prompt (cons %abort (cons k args)))))))
```

`call-with-prompt` will initiate a continuation a `set!` global called `%prompt` which means there is single prompt for `THUNK`. If the continuation arguments `OUT`, the second lambda of `call-with-values`, starts with the unique object `%abort` it means the continuation was reached via `abort-to-prompt`. It will call the `HANDLER` with the `abort-to-prompt` continuation and any argument passed to `call-with-prompt` continuation parameter that is the `(apply handler (cons k (cdr out)))`.

`abort-to-promp` will initiate a new continuation to be able to come back, after the code executes the prompt's continuation stored in `%prompt`.

The `call-with-prompt` is at the heart of the event-loop. Here is it, in two pieces:

```
(define (exec epoll thunk waiting)
  (call-with-prompt
   thunk
   (lambda (k fd mode) ;; k is abort-to-prompt continuation that
                       ;; will allow to restart the coroutine

     ;; add fd to the correct epoll set
     (case mode
       ((write) (epoll-wait-write epoll fd))
       ((read) (epoll-wait-read epoll fd))
       (else (error 'untangle "mode not supported" mode)))
     (scheme:hash-table-set! waiting fd (make-event k mode)))))

(define (event-loop-run-once epoll waiting)
  ;; execute every callback waiting in queue, 
  ;; call the above exec procedure 
  (let loop ()
    (unless (null? %queue)
      ;; XXX: This is done like that because, exec might spawn
      ;; new coroutine, so we need to cut %queue right now. 
      (let ((head (car %queue))
            (tail (cdr %queue)))
        (set! %queue tail)
        (exec epoll head waiting)
        (loop))))

    ;; wait for ONE event
    (let ((fd (epoll-wait-one epoll (inf))
      (let ((event (scheme:hash-table-ref waiting fd)))
        ;; the event is / will be processed, no need to keep around
        (scheme:hash-table-delete! waiting fd)
        (case (event-mode event)
          ((write) (epoll-ctl epoll 2 fd (make-epoll-event-out fd)))
          ((read) (epoll-ctl epoll 2 fd (make-epoll-event-in fd))))
        ;; here it will schedule the event continuation that is the
        ;; abort-to-prompt continuation that will be executed by the
        ;; next call the above event loop event-loop-run-once
        (spawn (event-continuation event))))))
```

I think that is all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chez-scheme, there is [chez-a-sync](https://github.com/ChrisVine/chez-a-sync/).  It uses POSIX poll rather than epoll (epoll is linux specific).  guile-a-sync2 is also available for guile-2.2/3.0.