# Can any case of using call/cc be rewritten equivalently without using it?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, continuations, callcc

Can any case of using `call/cc` be rewritten equivalently without using it?

For example

1. In `(g (call/cc f))`, is the purpose of `f` to evaluate the value of
   some `expression`, so that `g` can be applied to the value?

   Is `(g (call/cc f))` always able to be rewritten equivalently
   without `call/cc` e.g. `(g expression)`?
2. In `((call/cc f) arg)`, is the purpose of `f` to evaluate the
   definition of some function `g`, so that  function `g` can be
   applied to the value of `arg`?

   Is `((call/cc f) arg)` always able to be rewritten equivalently
   without `call/cc` e.g. `(g arg)`?

If the answers are yes, why do we need to use `call/cc`? 
I am trying to understand the purpose of using `call/cc`, by contrasting it to not using it.

Comment: Note that 2 is subcase of 1, where `g` defined as `(λ (h) (h arg))`.

Answer (score 4):

The key to the direct answer here is the notion of "Turing equivalence". That is, essentially all of the commonly used programming languages (C, Java, Scheme, Haskell, Lambda Calculus etc. etc.) are equivalent in the sense that for any program in one of these languages, there is a corresponding program in each of the other languages which has the same meaning.

Beyond this, though, some of these equivalences may be "nice" and some may be really horrible. This suggests that we reframe the question: which features can be rewritten in a "nice" way into languages without that feature, and which cannot?

A formal treatment of this comes from Matthias Felleisen, in his 1991 paper "On the Expressive Power of Programming Languages" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016764239190036W), which introduces a notion of macro expressibility, pointing out that some features can be rewritten in a local way, and some require global rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your original question is obviously yes. Scheme is Turing-complete, with or without `call/cc`, so even without `call/cc`, you can still compute anything that is computable.

> Why "it is more convenient than writing the equivalent expression using lambda"?

The classic paper [On the Expressive Power of Programming Languages](ftp://jcmc.indiana.edu/pub/scheme-repository/doc/pubs/express.ps.gz) by Matthias Felleisen gives one answer to this question. Pretty much, to rewrite a program with `call/cc` to one without it, you might potentially need to transform your whole program (global transformation). This is to contrast some other constructs that only need a local transformation (i.e., can be written as macro) to remove them.

Comment: Ha! I think you beat me by about 30 seconds :).

Answer (score 2):

The key is:  *If* your program is written in continuation passing style, you don't need `call/cc`. If not, good luck.

I whole-heartedly recommend:

Daniel P. Friedman. "Applications of Continuations: Invited Tutorial". 1988 Principles of Programming Languages (POPL88). January 1988

https://cs.indiana.edu/~dfried/appcont.pdf

If you enjoy reading that paper, then check out:
https://github.com/scheme-live/bibliography/blob/master/page6.md

Answer (score 1):

Of course anything that is written with `call/cc` can be written without it, because *everything* in Scheme is ultimately written using `lambda`. You use `call/cc` because it is more convenient than writing the equivalent expression using `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks. Why "it is more convenient than writing the equivalent expression using lambda"?

Comment: Look at the implementation of "Multitasking with Engines" at [https://www.scheme.com/tspl3/examples.html#g171](https://www.scheme.com/tspl3/examples.html#g171). Try to implement it without `call/cc` and let us know how you get on.

Comment: @Ben As simple expression as `(sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b)))` becomes `(*& a a (lambda (a2) (*& b b (lambda (b2) (+& a2 b2 (lambda (m) (sqrt& m continuation)))))` in CPS. Already this simple example is hard to follow in CPS. Imagine a hard example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two senses to this question: an uninteresting one and an interesting one:

**The uninteresting one.** Is there some computation that you can do with `call/cc` that you can't do in a language which does not have it?

No, there isn't: `call/cc` doesn't make a language properly more powerful: it is famously the case that a language with only λ and function application is equivalent to a universal Turing machine, and thus there is no (known...) more powerful computational system.

But that's kind of uninteresting from the point of view of programming-language design: subject to the normal constraints on memory &c, pretty much all programming languages are equivalent to UTMs, but people still prefer to use languages which don't involve punching holes in paper tape if they can.

**The interesting one.** Is it the case that `call/cc` makes some desirable features of a programming language easier to express?

The answer to this is yes, it does.  I'll just give a couple of examples.  Let's say you want to have some kind of non-local exit feature in your language, so some deeply-nested bit of program can just say 'to hell with this I want out', without having to climb back out through some great layer of functions.  This is *trivial* with `call/cc`: the continuation procedure *is* the escape procedure.  You can wrap it in some syntax if you want it to be nicer:

```
(define-syntax with-escape
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (e) form ...)
     (call/cc (λ (e) form ...))]))

(with-escape (e)
  ... code in here, and can call e to escape, and return some values ...)
```

Can you implement this without `call/cc`?  Well, yes, but not without either relying on some other special construct (say `block` and `return-from` in CL), or without turning the language inside out in some way.

And you can build on things like this to implement all sorts of non-local escapes.

Or, well, let's say you want GO TO (the following example is Racket):

```
(define (test n)
  (define m 0)
  (define start (call/cc (λ (c) c)))
  (printf "here ~A~%" m)
  (set! m (+ m 1))
  (when (< m n)
    (start start)))
```

Or, with some syntax around this:

```
(define-syntax-rule (label place)
  (define place (call/cc identity)))

(define (go place)
  (place place))

(define (horrid n)
  (define m 0)
  (label start)
  (printf "here ~A~%" m)
  (set! m (+ m 1))
  (when (< m n)
    (go start)))
```

So, OK, this perhaps is not a desirable feature of a programming language.  But, well, Scheme doesn't have GO TO right, and yet, here, it does.

So, yes, `call/cc` (especially when combined with macros) makes a lot of desirable features of a programming language possible to express.  Other languages have all these special-purpose, limited hacks, Scheme has this universal thing from which all these special-purpose hacks can be built.

The problem is that `call/cc` doesn't stop with the *good* special-purpose hacks: you can also build all the awful horrors that used to blight programming languages out of it.  `call/cc` is like having access to an elder god: it's really convenient if you want dread power, but you'd better be careful what comes with it when you call, because it may well  be an unspeakable horror from beyond spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

An easy use of `call/cc` is as a bail out. eg.

```
;; (1 2) => (2 4)
;; #f if one element is not a number
(define (double-numbers lst)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (exit)
     (let helper ((lst lst))
       (cond ((null? lst) '())
             ((not (number? (car lst))) (exit #f))
             (else (cons (* 2 (car lst)) (helper (cdr lst)))))))))
```

So to understand this. If we are doing `(double-numbers '(1 2 r))` the result is `#f`, but the helper has done `(cons 1 (cons 2 (exit #f)))`

Without `call/cc` we see the continuation would be whatever called `double-numbers` since it actually return normally from it. Here is an example without `call/cc`:

```
;; (1 2) => (2 4)
;; #f if one element is not a number
(define (double-numbers lst)
  (define (helper& lst cont)
    (cond ((null? lst) (cont '()))
          ((not (number? (car lst))) #f) ; bail out, not using cont
          (else (helper& (cdr lst)
                         (lambda (result)
                           (cont (cons (* 2 (car lst)) result)))))))
  (helper& lst values)) ; values works as an identity procedure
```

I imagine it gets harder pretty quick. Eg. [my generator implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30632051/1565698). The generator relies on having access to continuations to mix the generator code with where it's used, but without `call/cc` you'll need to do CPS in both the generator, the generated generator and the code that uses it.