# Using dot notation in Racket class functions

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I have following class which works fine:

```
(define myob%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (init-field val)
    (define/public (getval) val)
    (define/public (setval v) (set! val v))   ))

(define ob1 (make-object myob% 5))

(send ob1 getval)
(send ob1 setval 10)
(send ob1 getval)
```

Output:

```
5
10
```

Following regex also works well:

```
(define sl (regexp-match #px"^(.+)[.]([^.]+)$" "ob1.getval"))
sl
```

Output:

```
'("ob1.getval" "ob1" "getval")
```

I am trying to make a fn foo which should work like 'send' but take arguments in form of `(foo ob1.getval)` or `(foo ob1.setval 10)` . Following macro is not working:

```
(define-syntax foo
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ sstr ...)
       (define sl (regexp-match #px"^(.+)[.]([^.]+)$"
                                (symbol->string sstr)))
       (send (string->symbol(list-ref sl 1))
             (string->symbol(list-ref sl 2))
             ...))))

(foo ob1.getval)
```

The error is:

```
syntax-rules: bad syntax in: (syntax-rules () ((_ sstr ...) (define sl (regexp-match #px"^(.+)[.]([^.]+)$" (symbol->string sstr))) (send (list-ref sl 1) (list-ref sl 2) ...)))
```

Where is the error and how can this be corrected?

Comment: AFAIK, `sstr` denotes a syntax object, not a symbol, and needs converting with `syntax->datum`. (And the opposite problem for the `send`.)

Comment: Can you put it as an answer with correct code?

Comment: Unfortunately, fixing those issues isn't enough, and I'm not sure what the correct code would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use dot notation like this, you'll need to define a new `#lang` language, with its own reader. There are several tools to help with this, and I'll be using one of them, `syntax/module-reader`, to define `#lang send-dot`, which once defined can be used like this:

```
#lang send-dot

(define o
  (new (class object% (super-new)
         (define/public (f x) x))))

(o.f "hellooo")
```

In the [latest snapshot version](https://pre.racket-lang.org/) of Racket, you can use the [`read-cdot`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-cdot%29%29) option. Make sure you're on the latest snapshot version, since in 6.6, it's completely broken.

One way to define a `#lang` is by declaring a `reader` submodule. Make a directory called `send-dot`, and add a file called `main.rkt`. This file should provide everything from racket.

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-from-out racket))
```

This doesn't define a `#lang` yet. But to try it out, you can go to DrRacket's File menu, click on Package Manager, and in the Package Source field, enter the path to the `send-dot` directory. Once you do that, you should be able to use `#lang s-exp send-dot` in another file just like you would `#lang racket`.

To define a reader for this language and make it a real `#lang` language, you can add a `reader` submodule that uses `syntax/module-reader` as its language.

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-from-out racket))

;; This submodule defines the reader for the language
(module reader syntax/module-reader
  send-dot)
```

Now you should be able to use `#lang send-dot` just like `#lang racket`.

Now you need to do two more things. One, turn on the [`read-cdot`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-cdot%29%29) option so that `(o.method args ...)` is translated to `((#%dot o method) args ...)`, and Two, define a `#%dot` macro so that `((#%dot o method) args ...)` is equivalent to `(send o method args ...)`.

For the first thing, you can use the `#:wrapper1` option, using `parameterize` to turn [`read-cdot`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-cdot%29%29) on.

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-from-out racket))

;; This submodule defines the reader for the language
(module reader syntax/module-reader
  send-dot
  #:wrapper1 (lambda (thunk)
               ;; turns on the read-cdot option,
               ;; which will turn o.method into (#%dot o method),
               ;; and (o.method args ...) into ((#%dot o method) args ...)
               (parameterize ([read-cdot #true])
                 (thunk))))
```

For the second thing, you need to define a `#%dot` macro. `o.method`, or `(#%dot o method)`, needs to be a function that calls the method, so you can use `(lambda args (send/apply o method args))`.

```
#lang racket

(provide #%dot (all-from-out racket))

;; transforms (#%dot o method) into a function that calls the method
;; so that ((#%dot o method) args ...) will be roughly equivalent to
;; (send o method args ...)
(define-syntax-rule (#%dot obj-expr method-id)
  (let ([obj obj-expr])
    (lambda args (send/apply obj method-id args))))

;; This submodule defines the reader for the language
(module reader syntax/module-reader
  send-dot
  #:wrapper1 (lambda (thunk)
               ;; turns on the read-cdot option,
               ;; which will turn o.method into (#%dot o method),
               ;; and (o.method args ...) into ((#%dot o method) args ...)
               (parameterize ([read-cdot #true])
                 (thunk))))
```

Now you should be able to use `#lang send-dot` like this:

```
#lang send-dot

(define o
  (new (class object% (super-new)
         (define/public (f x) x))))

(o.f "hellooo")
```

Comment: Great. Can you briefly add here itself how dot can also be used for structure elements in this new language (with reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145000/macro-to-use-dot-notation-to-get-structure-fields-in-racket )

Comment: Objects are easier because they can rely on dynamic dispatch. Structs would be a bit harder if you wanted `mydog.name`, but it might be easier if you wanted `mydog.dog-name` to be translated to `(dog-name mydog)`

Comment: Code to convert mydog.dog-name to (dog-name mydog) will be appreciated here. Or will it just work because read-cdot is active here. I believe it will have to be used without parentheses. Is that right?